# PHP rot13 with ASCII

Tags: php, encoding

I want to make simple encryption with rot13, but i don't want use function str_rot13(), because I want add numbers on it and I think str_rot13() isn't supported.
I have found code like this and want to edit, but I don't know how

```
<?php 

$string = "Hello World 123";

for ($i = 0, $j = strlen( $string); $i < $j; $i++) 
{
    // Get the ASCII character for the current character
    $char = ord( $string[$i]); 


    // If that character is in the range A-Z or a-z, add 13 to its ASCII value
    if( ($char >= 65  && $char <= 90) || ($char >= 97 && $char <= 122)) 
    {
        $char += 13; 

        // If we should have wrapped around the alphabet, subtract 26
        if( $char > 122 || ( $char > 90 && ord( $string[$i]) < 97)) 
        {
            $char -= 26;
        }
    }
    echo chr( $char);
}

 ?>
```

this code have result "Uryyb Jbeyq 123". What I want is add number 0-9 on it, so encryption become rot18 -> a-z0123456789. Result of this so become "Zw336 E693v JKL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Str_rot13` is an encoding-decoding function which means `str_rot13(str_rot13('some string here'))==='some string here'`.The most efficient way to build such function  according to me, is to use simple internal map.In PHP we can use array indexed from 1 to 36 to achieve this instead of use ASCII code. With ASCII code You will face difficulties to make an encoding-decoding function easily and thus your algorithm will be less fast .Below is a basic implementation of a str_rot18 encoding-decoding function as esplained above:

```
 function str_rot18($string){
    if(!is_string($string)) return false; 
    $map=array (
      'a' => 1, 'b' => 2,'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6,'g' => 7,'h' => 8,
      'i' => 9,
      'j' => 10,'k' => 11,'l' => 12,'m' => 13,'n' => 14,'o' => 15,'p' => 16,'q' => 17,
      'r' => 18,
      's' => 19,'t' => 20, 'u' => 21,'v' => 22,'w' => 23,'x' => 24,'y' => 25,'z' => 26,
       0 => 27,1 => 28,2 => 29,3 => 30,4 => 31,5 => 32,6 => 33,7 => 34,8 => 35,9 => 36,
    );
    $flipped_map=array (
      1 => 'a',2 => 'b',3 => 'c',4 => 'd',5 => 'e',6 => 'f',7 => 'g',8 => 'h',9 => 'i',
      10 => 'j',11 => 'k',12 => 'l',13 => 'm',14 => 'n',15 => 'o',16 => 'p',17 => 'q',
      18 => 'r',19 => 's',20 => 't',21 => 'u',22 => 'v',23 => 'w',24 => 'x',25 => 'y',
      26 => 'z',27 => 0,28 => 1,29 => 2,30 => 3,31 => 4,32 => 5,33 => 6,34 => 7,35 => 8,
      36 => 9,
    );

    for ($i = 0, $j = strlen( $string); $i < $j; $i++) 
    {
        if(!ctype_digit($string[$i])){
            $char=mb_strtolower($string[$i]);
        }
        else $char=(int)$string[$i];

        if(isset($map[$char])){
            $tmp = $map[$char]+18; 
            $tmp=($tmp>36)?$tmp-36:$tmp;
            if(!ctype_lower($string[$i])&&!ctype_digit($string[$i]))
                $string[$i]=mb_strtoupper($flipped_map[$tmp]);
            else
                $string[$i]=$flipped_map[$tmp];
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
```

**Of course this can be improved but it is already a good starting point...**

However **if you really want to use ASCII code i suggest** to use the full ASCII map to allow all characters and keep the spirit of an fast and easy to implement encoding-decoding function .So your function will be a `str_rot128` instead of `str_rot18`:

```
function str_rot128($string){
    if(!is_string($string)) return false; 
    for ($i = 0, $j = strlen( $string); $i < $j; $i++) 
    {
        // Get the ASCII character for the current character
        $char=ord($string[$i])+128;
        $char=$char>256?$char-256:$char;
        $string[$i]=chr($char); 
    }
    return $string;
}
```

You can see a working code here:
[Alternative to str_rot13 using more characters than a-z](https://3v4l.org/YEPOG)

Comment: thank you so much for your help. your advice help me a lot

Comment: @AchmadRifanni I'm happy that i could help you.If you think this answer solved your issue don't forget to mark the question as solved...